# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Error:

"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`."

index.js

```js
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import App from './App';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in the Expo client or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);
```

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavigationCointainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Favoritos from './Favoritos';
import InfoGeneral from './InfoGeneral';
import Principal from './Principal';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <NavigationCointainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Principal'>
          <Stack.Screen name='Principal' component={Principal}/>
          <Stack.Screen name='InfoGeneral' component={InfoGeneral}/>
          <Stack.Screen name='Favoritos' component={Favoritos}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationCointainer>
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: `NavigationContainer` is misspelled as `NavigationCointainer`.

Comment: that was it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error, it means you are trying to render `undefined` as a component. This usually happens in circumstances like this:

MyComponent.js:

```
function MyComponent() {
   return <View />;
}
```

App.js

```
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';

export default function App() {
  return <MyComponent />;
}
```

Can you spot what is missing? It's `export` from `MyComponent.js`. In App.js, `MyComponent` is undefined because there is no such export. To fix it, you would do this:

MyComponent.js:

```
export function MyComponent() {
   return <View />;
}
```

Comment: The 3 components (Principal, Favoritos and InfoGeneral) have their exports like this: export default class Principal extends Component{

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I tried to get rid of warnings about **PascalCase**.

The warning:

> Imported JSX component text must be in PascalCase or
> SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE *react/jsx-pascal-case*

I changed all components in my React Redux Form from Control.text, Control.select, Control.textarea to Control.Text, Control.Select, Control.TextArea and started getting this error.

I changed

```
<Control.Text />
<Control.Select />
<Control.TextArea />
```

back to

```
<Control.text />
<Control.select />
<Control.textarea />
```

and the error was gone.